# Why am I getting 'void' type not allowed here?

Tags: java, string, tostring

I am trying to make a toString for a board of cards.
When I try to compile I am told "void type not allowed here" and it points me to this line:

```
  visualBoard = visualBoard + row + System.out.println();
```

Here it is at the end with the whole method.

```
  /**
  Makes a visual representation of the board.
  @param game board
  @return String visual of the board.
  */
  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
     String visualBoard = "";
     //For loop for each spot on board
     for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++){
        String row = "";
        for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++){
           //Adding the board square to the current string.
           BoardSquare current = board.get(r).get(c);
           row += current.getCard(r,c).toString() + "_";
        }
        visualBoard = visualBoard + row + System.out.println();

     }
     return visualBoard;
  }
```

I'm really confused as to why they are telling me row is a void type since I did put a string in it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you think `System.out.println()` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: I though it would jump to the next line.

Comment: You're probably looking for `System.lineSeparator()`

Comment: You can always use `"\n"` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void` on a method means no return value.

`System.out.println` is void and does therefore not return a value.

Therefore the `+` does not have anything to add, and the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
visualBoard = visualBoard + row + System.out.println();
```

System.out.println() does not return a string value to its caller, its return type is void. It just prints any string arguments on the stdout stream. That is why you are getting that error.

If you want to concatenate an empty string to something, this is the way to do it:

```
visualBoard = visualBoard + row + "";
```